# Simple Windows on the bottom of GoogleMap in AndroidStudio in Kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am currently developing an android app for one of my university subjects. At this point I have a GoogleMaps map with several markers, which mark locations of interest. That doesn't really matter. I'm trying to make a windows pop up whenever I click any of the markers. The window is supposed to fill the lower third of the screen and contain informations about the marker location. I already added an OnMarkerCLickListener to the map and the onMarkerCLick()-method is called whenever I press on a marker, but I really can't figure out how to set up such a window. I get that AndroidStudio has kind of a scene builder which I can use to design the Window, but how do I show it and how do I control where it pops up on the screen? I hope somebody can help me. I'm also new to Kotlin. In the past I did a lot with Java.
Heres a link to the current state of the app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFrEC.jpg

Heres my code for the MapsActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.multimodaltraffic
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.multimodaltraffic.api.ApiRequests
import com.example.multimodaltraffic.api.stations.NetworkJson
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.awaitResponse
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory


const val BASE_URL = "https://api.citybik.es"

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1

    private fun getLocationAccess() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        }
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST)
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.contains(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return
                }
                mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "User has not granted location access permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        getLocationAccess()
        // Placeholder for camera start position
        // @TODO change to current position
        val kassel =LatLng(51.313139, 9.465458)
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(kassel, 8f))
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
        // current zoom level
        /*
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener {
            Log.d("DEBUG",mMap.cameraPosition.zoom.toString())
        }
        */

        getCurrentData()
    }

    /**
     * Get data from CityBikes API
     * First all networks, then all stations of the networks
     * Calls function to add markers on map
     * */
    private fun getCurrentData() {

        var api = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ApiRequests::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            try {
                val response = api.getNextbikeData().awaitResponse()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    var networks = response.body()!!

                    networks.networks.forEach{
                        if(it.location.country == "DE"){
                            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                api = Retrofit.Builder()
                                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                        .build()
                                        .create(ApiRequests::class.java)

                                val response = api.getStations(it.id).awaitResponse()

                                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                                    var network = response.body()!!
                                    setStationMarker(network)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            "Nextbike networks could not be loaded.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add marker for each Nextbike station
    private fun setStationMarker(network: NetworkJson){
        // @TODO Safe marker to update informations

        network.network.stations.forEach{

            val station = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
            this@MapsActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                if (it.freeBikes > 0) {
                    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                            .position(station)
                            .title(it.name)
                            .snippet("Free bikes: " + it.freeBikes)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                    )

                } else {
                    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                            .position(station)
                            .title(it.name)
                            .snippet("Free bikes: " + it.freeBikes)
                    )
                }
            })


        }
    }

    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?): Boolean {
        if (p0 != null) {
            p0.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Here's the code of my maps_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: You could add a hidden layout into your `activity_maps` and change its visibility and data with the click of the markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Called BottomSheetDialogFragment.

Here some reference [MindOrks Tutorial](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-bottomsheet-in-kotlin) and [Medium](https://medium.com/@naingwinhtun.iam/create-a-bottom-sheet-in-android-with-kotlin-21d6482ba3ec)

And here what my sugestion

1. Create Fragment First, i'll call it BottomDialogFragment
2. Change Fragment() to BottomSheetDialogFragment()

```
class BottomDialogFragment : Fragment()
class BottomDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment()
```

3. Design your layout
4. Change Inside BottomDialogFragment into

```
class BottomDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        val TAG : String = BottomDialogFragment::class.java.simpleName
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_dialog_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        //do whatever you want in here 
        //e.g: Handle Button Click etc

    }

}
```

5. Call BottomDialogFragment when User clicked the marker

```
override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?): Boolean {
        if (p0 != null) {
          p0.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
          //call it like this
          BottomDialogFragment.newInstance().apply {
              show(supportFragmentManager, BottomDialogFragment.TAG)
          }
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitly try this and report to you if it worked! :-)

Comment: I tried to implement it this way but i have a problem with my activity_maps.xml file. How do I add the code of the activity_main.xml file from MIndOrks tutorial to my existing activity_maps.xml file without messing up? The code from my current .xml file can be found above :-)

Comment: you actually dont have to change your activity_main.xml